# Express + Request Changing headers mid-stream

Tags: node.js, caching, express, header, request

I'm using express as my server and request to retrieve content from an up-stream box.

I've got this beautifully simple function to stream data from the up-stream to the client:

```
function(req, res){
  request("http://example.com").pipe(res);
}
```

The upstream box is returning a cache header `Cache-Control: no-cache` that I'd like to modify, so that Nginx (reverse proxy) can cache the response.

Where should I put the `res.header('Cache-Control', 60);`?

I've tried:

```
function(req, res){
  var retrieve = request("http://example.com");
  retrieve.on('data', function(chunk){
    if(res.get('Cache-Control') != 60)
      res.header('Cache-Control', 60);
  });
  retrieve.pipe(res);
}
```

But this throws a `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent` error.

Is there a listener that fires when the headers are sent, but before `writeHeader()` is called?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032451/266795 and https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: Perfect!  Nice and simple.  I'll add an answer once I'm allowed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [Peter Lyons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266795/peter-lyons), I was able to get this working using this code:

```
function(req, res){
  request("http://example.com").pipe(res);

  res.oldWriteHead = res.writeHead;
  res.writeHead = function(statusCode, reasonPhrase, headers){
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=60, public');
    res.oldWriteHead(statusCode, reasonPhrase, headers);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It seems request has been updated since the accepted answer was submitted, making this process much easier. You can now do the following:

```
var resource = request('http://example.com');

resource.on('response', function(response) {
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=60, public';
});

resource.pipe(res);
```

Much nicer!

Comment: Take a look at the [request library](https://github.com/request/request). Basically, `request('http://example.com')` starts loading example.com and returns a [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). Streams have an `.on()` method that allows you to listen for certain events, such as `'response'`, which is triggered when example.com has finished loading. When that happens, we set the cache control header. Finally, `resource.pipe(res)` takes the requst stream and redirects it back to `res`, which we can assume is what's being returned to the end user's browser. Does that make sense?