# I need to remove or ignore the X-Frame-Options header. Should I use a proxy?

Tags: node.js, iframe, proxy, http-headers, squid

### Premise

I need a way to remove the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header from the responses from [a](https://www.nytimes.com/) [few](https://www.ksl.com/) [websites](https://calendar.google.com/) before those responses reach [my browser](https://packages.debian.org/buster/chromium).

I am doing this so that I can properly render [my custom kiosk webpage](https://www.danpurdy.co.uk/web-development/raspberry-pi-kiosk-screen-tutorial/), which has `iframe`s that point to websites that [don't want to show up in frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller).

### What I have tried

I have tried setting up a proxy using [`squid`](http://www.squid-cache.org) and configuring its [`reply_header_access`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.5/cfgman/reply_header_access.html) option to `deny` `X-Frame-Options` headers as the server receives them, but that is for some reason not working as anticipated. I have verified that I am indeed going through the Squid proxy, and I have verified that the `X-Frame-Options` header persists despite my `squid.conf` file containing the following:

```
reply_header_access X-Frame-Options deny all
```

and having built `squid` (using Homebrew on my Mac) with the `--enable-http-violations` option.

Having chased down a lot of what might have gone wrong with this approach, I have decided that the `reply_header_access` option must not do exactly what I thought it does (modify headers before returning them to the client).

So, I tried using another proxy server. After reading [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755865/rewrite-response-headers-with-node-http-proxy) asking about a situation roughly similar to mine, I decided I might try using the [`node-http-proxy`](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy) library. However, I have never used Node before, so I got lost pretty quickly and am stuck at a point where I am not sure how to implement the library for my specific purpose.

### Question

Using Node seems like a potentially very easy solution, so how can I set up a proxy using Node that removes the `X-Frame-Options` header from responses?

Alternatively, why is Squid not removing the header even though I tried to set it up to do so?

Final alternative: Is there an easier way to reach my ultimate goal of rendering any page I want within an `iframe`?

Comment: have you managed to set up proxyy and bypass x-frame-options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a proxy, specifically [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org) with the following script:

`drop_unwanted_headers.py:`

```py
import mitmproxy

def requestheaders(flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    for each_key in flow.request.headers:
        if each_key.casefold().startswith("sec-".casefold()):
            flow.request.headers.pop(each_key)

def responseheaders(flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if "x-frame-options" in flow.response.headers:
        flow.response.headers.pop("x-frame-options")
    if "content-security-policy" in flow.response.headers:
        flow.response.headers.pop("content-security-policy")
```

To run it, do:
`mitmproxy --script drop_unwanted_headers.py`

Also ensure that your proxy settings point to the computer where the proxy server is running (maybe `localhost`) and the correct port is used.

Comment: How to run this script using mitmproxy?

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK I guess they don't make it obvious in [the documentation](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-scripting/), do they… I will add this to my answer.